# Filter date time every six hours in R

Tags: r, filter, time, subset

I am new to R and I am trying to filter my data set to avoid auto correlation. My data set consists of more than 50.000 locations ($ longitude and $ latitude) of 25 GPS collard animals with a date time stamp ($ acquisition_time) and some additional info (age class, sex, study area). I need to filter a set of locations for every individual ($animals_id) including only locations with acquisition times min. 6 hours apart. I would first group the data by individual and acquisition_time but I don't know how to write the filter function.

this is a subset of my data set:

```
     animals_id    acquisition_time longitude latitude      projection
8663         74 2018-02-17 03:00:24  6.426237 50.31815 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8664         74 2018-02-17 13:00:48  6.428196 50.31657 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8665         74 2018-02-17 18:00:24  6.423940 50.31833 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8666         74 2018-02-18 14:00:24  6.420372 50.31563 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8667         74 2018-02-18 19:00:54  6.420273 50.31534 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8668         74 2018-02-19 00:00:24  6.415756 50.31993 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8669         74 2018-02-19 20:00:24  6.415771 50.31927 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8670         78 2017-05-01 01:00:08  6.337308 50.26133 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8671         78 2017-05-01 06:00:23  6.345836 50.25292 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8672         78 2017-05-01 11:00:41  6.345818 50.25295 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8673         78 2017-05-01 16:00:23  6.345813 50.25287 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8674         78 2017-05-01 21:00:12  6.343215 50.25456 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8675         78 2017-05-02 02:00:23  6.342139 50.25576 EPSG:4326-WGS48
8676         78 2017-05-02 07:00:47  6.352676 50.25308 EPSG:4326-WGS48
     collar_type study_area_id animals_age_class animals_sex
8663         gps            15                 a           f
8664         gps            15                 a           f
8665         gps            15                 a           f
8666         gps            15                 a           f
8667         gps            15                 a           f
8668         gps            15                 a           f
8669         gps            15                 a           f
8670         gps            15                 a           f
8671         gps            15                 a           f
8672         gps            15                 a           f
8673         gps            15                 a           f
8674         gps            15                 a           f
8675         gps            15                 a           f
8676         gps            15                 a           f
>
```

My code so far:

```
data$acquisition_time = as.POSIXct(data$acquisition_time, tz = "UTC", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

filtered <- data %>% group_by(animals_id,acquisition_time) %>% filter()
```

I appreciate every tip.

Comment: Your sample data is already no-more-frequent than 6 hours. Question though: is it *"every 6 hours"* (suggesting interpolation, probably not right to do here) or *"no more frequent than 6 hours"*? Please update your sample data; ideally, it should have at least 2 (but not many) distinct `animals_id`, and some rows that are too frequent and some that are not.

Comment: sorry I corrected it, I only showed the head of my data set. I have over 50.000 rows with more than 25 individuals and the frequency of the fixes is different for all individuals. So I have to be sure to have locations for every individuals that are minimal 6 hours apart.

Comment: I understand, it is a common issue on SO to not be able to post a lot of data. Your data is insufficient, though, in that what you *need* is a group-wise filtering of too-frequent data, and what you *provide* is one animal where all rows already meet your needs.

Comment: I only wanted to give an idea of my data. I now provided a subset of my data where you can see different individuals. I hope this is more suitable now.

Comment: I understand, and it is often not terribly difficult to generate fake data; having an idea how your real data is structured is key. However ... for expediency, some answerers do not always have a lot of time to devote to answering something here, so it is to your distinct advantage to reduce our "cost of entry" (the amount of time we have to spend to *work with your data*) to improve the chances of getting a prompt and appropriate suggestion. Hope this helps clarify my comments.

Comment: I understand. I will keep it in mind and next time provide suitable data right away. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Good to know, I will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick view of the data and the time between acquisition times:

```
     animals_id    acquisition_time longitude latitude     hours
8663         74 2018-02-17 03:00:24  6.426237 50.31815  0.000000
8664         74 2018-02-17 13:00:48  6.428196 50.31657 10.006667
8665         74 2018-02-17 18:00:24  6.423940 50.31833  4.993333
8666         74 2018-02-18 14:00:24  6.420372 50.31563 20.000000
8667         74 2018-02-18 19:00:54  6.420273 50.31534  5.008333
8668         74 2018-02-19 00:00:24  6.415756 50.31993  4.991667
8669         74 2018-02-19 20:00:24  6.415771 50.31927 20.000000
8670         78 2017-05-01 01:00:08  6.337308 50.26133  0.000000
8671         78 2017-05-01 06:00:23  6.345836 50.25292  5.004167
8672         78 2017-05-01 11:00:41  6.345818 50.25295  5.005000
8673         78 2017-05-01 16:00:23  6.345813 50.25287  4.995000
8674         78 2017-05-01 21:00:12  6.343215 50.25456  4.996944
8675         78 2017-05-02 02:00:23  6.342139 50.25576  5.003056
8676         78 2017-05-02 07:00:47  6.352676 50.25308  5.006667
```

To me, this means for id `74`, we'll drop rows 8665 and 8667; for id `78`, we'll drop rows  8671, 8673, and 8675. Doing that will result in all observations between no less than 6 hours apart, per `animals_id`.

### base R

```r
func <- function(z, period = 6*3600) {
  if (length(z) < 2) return(rep(TRUE, length(z)))
  out <- TRUE
  ind <- 1
  while (ind < length(z)) {
    found <- which( (z[-seq_len(ind)] - z[ind]) >= period )
    if (!length(found)) {
      out <- c(out, rep(FALSE, length(z) - length(out)))
      break
    }
    out <- c(out, rep(FALSE, found[1] - 1), TRUE)
    ind <- ind + found[1]
  }
  out
}

dat[ave(as.numeric(dat$acquisition_time, units = "sec"), dat$animals_id, FUN = func) > 0,]
#      animals_id    acquisition_time longitude latitude
# 8663         74 2018-02-17 03:00:24  6.426237 50.31815
# 8664         74 2018-02-17 13:00:48  6.428196 50.31657
# 8666         74 2018-02-18 14:00:24  6.420372 50.31563
# 8668         74 2018-02-19 00:00:24  6.415756 50.31993
# 8669         74 2018-02-19 20:00:24  6.415771 50.31927
# 8670         78 2017-05-01 01:00:08  6.337308 50.26133
# 8672         78 2017-05-01 11:00:41  6.345818 50.25295
# 8674         78 2017-05-01 21:00:12  6.343215 50.25456
# 8676         78 2017-05-02 07:00:47  6.352676 50.25308
```

(Note: base R's `ave` has a major restriction that the return value from the provided `FUN`ction must be the same class as the input vector; when the input is `POSIXt`, this causes a few problems. To mitigate these, I preemptively convert the times temporarily to `numeric` for the call to `ave`. This is not required in all group-summarizing functions in base R, just `ave`, though it is otherwise the most apt for this purpose.)

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(animals_id) %>%
  filter(func(acquisition_time)) %>%
  # not necessary, just here to show the resulting hours-between-times
  mutate(hours = c(0, diff(acquisition_time, units = "hours"))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 9 x 5
#   animals_id acquisition_time    longitude latitude hours
#        <int> <dttm>                  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1         74 2018-02-17 03:00:24      6.43     50.3  0   
# 2         74 2018-02-17 13:00:48      6.43     50.3 10.0 
# 3         74 2018-02-18 14:00:24      6.42     50.3 25.0 
# 4         74 2018-02-19 00:00:24      6.42     50.3 10   
# 5         74 2018-02-19 20:00:24      6.42     50.3 20   
# 6         78 2017-05-01 01:00:08      6.34     50.3  0   
# 7         78 2017-05-01 11:00:41      6.35     50.3 10.0 
# 8         78 2017-05-01 21:00:12      6.34     50.3  9.99
# 9         78 2017-05-02 07:00:47      6.35     50.3 10.0
```

(Note that `dplyr` drops row-names. I added the `hours` column just to demonstrate the resulting time differences, it is not required in production.)

---

Data: I used just the first four from your data above for simplicity/MWE.

```r
dat <- structure(list(animals_id = c(74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 74L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L, 78L), acquisition_time = structure(c(1518836424, 1518872448, 1518890424, 1518962424, 1518980454, 1518998424, 1519070424, 1493600408, 1493618423, 1493636441, 1493654423, 1493672412, 1493690423, 1493708447), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), longitude = c(6.426237, 6.428196, 6.42394, 6.420372, 6.420273, 6.415756, 6.415771, 6.337308, 6.345836, 6.345818, 6.345813, 6.343215, 6.342139, 6.352676), latitude = c(50.31815, 50.31657, 50.31833, 50.31563, 50.31534, 50.31993, 50.31927, 50.26133, 50.25292, 50.25295, 50.25287, 50.25456, 50.25576, 50.25308 )), row.names = c("8663", "8664", "8665", "8666", "8667", "8668", "8669", "8670", "8671", "8672", "8673", "8674", "8675", "8676"), class = "data.frame")
```